# Using JFrame, how can I get the enter key to trigger the same result as pressing the button?

Tags: java, swing, triggers, jframe, jbutton

I've searched, but I haven't found an answer that I understand. Currently, I have found posts that ask questions about triggering all events and such, but I only need one event triggered. This code is for a login box.

Edit: The button that I need triggered by "ENTER" is the login button.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
/**
 * Write a description of class Login here.
 * 
 * @author () 
 * @version ()
*/
public class LoginFrame extends JFrame
{
private JTextField statusField = new JTextField(20);
private JTextField usernameField = new JTextField(10);
private String usernameText;
private JTextField passwordField = new JTextField(10);
private String passwordText;
private JButton loginButton = new JButton("Log in");
private JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

public static void main() {
    LoginFrame app = new LoginFrame();
    app.setVisible(true);
    app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public LoginFrame() {
    super("Login");
    statusField.setText("Enter Username and Password");
    statusField.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    statusField.setEditable(false);
    add(statusField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    p.add(new JLabel("User name:"));
    p.add(usernameField);
    usernameText = usernameField.getText();
    p.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
    p.add(passwordField);
    passwordText =passwordField.getText();
    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Box buttonBar = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    buttonBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    buttonBar.add(cancelButton);
    buttonBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    buttonBar.add(loginButton);
    buttonBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    add(buttonBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent cancel) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent login) {
                statusField.setText("Authenticating...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //Handle exception
                }
                if ((usernameText == "abc") && (passwordText == "123"))
                {
                    statusField.setText("Valid Username and Password");
                }
                else
                {
                    statusField.setText("Invalid: Locked Out");
                    usernameField.setEditable(false);
                    passwordField.setEditable(false);
                }

            }
        });
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(335, 55));
    pack();
}
```

}

Comment: `I've searched, but I haven't found an answer that I understand` - so post the code you don't understand or post a link to the page you don't understand. We are not mind readers. We don't know what you don't understand. We don't want to waste time making the same suggestions. `but I only need one event triggered` - what do you mean you only need one event triggered? You have two buttons. Do you want the "Login" button triggered by default even if it doesn't have focus? Or do you want the button triggered when it does have focus?

Answer (score 1):

Is it when you press Enter on username/password field the event will trigger?
Just add ActionListener in those to fields, it will automatically trigger the event when you press Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Right click on your jtextfield Proprieties/Events/KeyPressed

//Inside the event
int key = evt.getKeyCode();
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
//Your Code

}//No Else
```

Comment: To improve this answer you should explain how they get the evt object you are acting upon. ie. do they register a key listener?)